# Should I switch my main OS to something more suitable for coding?

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

I want to take my python coding a lot further in the recent weeks and thought it would be a good idea to switch to something like Kali Linux or Ubuntu as they come built in with those things. I also want to be able to carry out my daily tasks like Youtube and gaming on Steam and such. Will switching to Linux hinder my choices of games I will be able to play and also would you recommend it and if so which OS?

Thank you :D

Comment: Linux is great for programming, but I believe windows supports more games. However I don't think this question is appropriate for StackOverflow

Comment: More games run in Windows, but there are plenty that run in Linux these days.  However, this question is off-topic for StackOverflow, for several reasons: not actually a programming question, and primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it will limit your choice of games, yes.  (Windows is probably still the most-supported OS for games.)

However, you should test the waters by installing Linux in a VM, e.g. using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), and see if you find it more suitable as a programming environment.  If you *really* like it, you might prefer to use a dual-boot setup where you boot into Windows for games, and boot into Linux for your programming experiments.  Good luck!

Comment: Another option is to dual boot. Windows for games, Linux for programming.

Comment: That's what I said in my answer, but maybe you posted this comment before my edit. :)

Comment: Yeah, I posted before the up date.

Comment: Yeh, dual-booting sounds like a great thing for me right now because I have messed around with Ubuntu in a VM before and really liked it (The only reason I am switching from that is because it runs kinda slow due to running both Ubuntu and Windows when I have the VM open) Two things I will need to ask before I can continue. How would I go about dual-booting without buggering everything up and also from your guys experiences which do you think is the best bet in the Linux OS range to go for?

Comment: For a beginner I would probably say Ubuntu as it's quite popular and there are tons of tutorials.  I would google for a dual-boot tutorial for Ubuntu and your version of Windows.  But to be safe I would also make sure I had a backup!

Comment: To be honest, a lot of people say get a backup but a lot of the time I just dont bother because I really dont have any incredibly important on Windows which I need to keep. Be I will keep that in mind. :) Thank you for the help.

Comment: I will update you guys later on :)